# How to show particular div using angularjs routing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

- Header contents=>main menu name is service and its submenu's are abc,def,pqr. This is in index.html
- And service.html have 3 separate div's one shows contains of abc,two shows contains of def and three shows contains of pqr.
- There is angularjs route call from index.html when I click header menu (i.e.service=>abc or def or pqr) then it should show its particular div other will not be shown.

Comment: you should have a look  on UI Router, maybe thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the menu items as parameters passed in the url and then use a an `ng-switch` or `ng-show` to show the selected content.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo : '/'
    })
...
    .when('/menu/:item', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'indexController'
    })
```

in controler, inject `$routeParams`:

```
app.controller('indexController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.menuItem = $routeParams.item;
});
```

in index:

```
<div ng-show='menuItem == "abc">abc</div>
<div ng-show='menuItem == "def">def</div>
<div ng-show='menuItem == "pqr">pqr</div>
```

Added benefit, you do not have to create new routes to create new menus with content in the index.html

downside, gets crowded in index.html

Comment: Yes this is what I expected.Actually I was trying the same but wasn't able to fetch sent parameter, This is the sufficient for me(app.controller('indexController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.menuItem = $routeParams.item;
});) 
Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

put ng-view tag in index.html
download angular route and inject this dependency into your app.
put routing code like

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo : '/user'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'client_assets/views/register.html',
        controller: 'registerController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'client_assets/views/log_in.html',
        controller: 'logInController'
    })
})
```

Now according to the route decide html template and controller you want to add.